# LARAVEL - send mail with domain email

Tags: laravel, email

I have a problem with sending mail by domain mail as follows:
My .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.my-domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@my-domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

It reported the following error:

```
Connection could not be established with host mail.my-domain.vn [Network is unreachable #101]
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you have the mail server already configured?

Comment: set `MAIL_DRIVER=mail`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But it reported an error proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: Are you using any email service ?

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem as you and eventually tried a different approach and it worked! 
you can use [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to achieve your goal. it'll be install easily using composer :

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

import your needs

```
use Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

and below is the code you need to modify

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'your_mail_host';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'Your username';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*********';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('your_mail_host', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('Receiver Mail address', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('your_mail_host');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you have not configured mail server, do it using cpanel or any other server tools available. You should then get the required mail configuration details which can be used in your .env file.

From the reported error, please also check the host name is "mail.my-domain.vn" and in the .env it is "mail.my-domain.com"

After setting up the .env with proper mail configuration details, please try to clear .env cache :

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan cache:clear`

After this try if you can send emails.

Note:

There is a fake smtp testing server named "mailtrap" which is for dummy smtp email testing.

https://mailtrap.io/

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did the above but still reported the error.When I use google mail then it works and domain mail is not

Answer (score 0):

Change port to 587

```
MAIL_MAILER= smtp MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= no-reply@domain.com MAIL_PASSWORD=your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION= tls MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@domain.com
```